# Free ribbon control for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, components, ribbon

I was wondering if there were any free ribbon controls for vb.net, and if there are not, how I could go about making my own. I don't want to pay $300 or more for a professional one...and I would really like to add one to my project.

What would be the best solution for finding/making one?
[Here](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS338US338&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free+ribbon+component+vb.net) is my google search I tried, I could only find one for c#...

If possible, I would like one which is the closest to the one used in Office 2007.

Comment: bear in mind that if your time is worth $50/hour, a $300 library is well worth it unless you could write the same thing yourself in less than 6 hours.

Comment: Too bad my time is not worth $50 an hour lol.

Comment: Lol: this question posted only 3 hrs ago is now the top result for that search.

Comment: Stack Overflow has amazing SEO lol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one that takes a bit of converting, but it works well in visual basic.

http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=66698&lngWId=1

old - Here is a basic one for Windows forms.  (c#, but I am sure I got this working in a vb project :S)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/WinFormsRibbon.aspx

Comment: This is the c# one I just deleted off my computer, it won't work with VB :(

Comment: edited - found the link! can't believe how many bookmarks I have!

Comment: The new one is only for vb6. If you can figure out how to make the link on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx work, lemme know. If you can explain how to make the c# one work for vb, please, let me know lol...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two free one's I've found:

- http://ribbon.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/WinFormsRibbon.aspx